# How do I Upload Files to my Web Server Through a Webpage on the Server in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, file

I would like to upload files to my web server, only I would like to be able to do it through a webpage on my server so that anybody can upload a file onto my server. I would prefer to only use HTML5 and JavaScript.

I appreciate any help,

Griffin

Comment: This is not enough information to answer your question. What backend scripting language are you using? What have you tried? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I honeslty have no idea where to start. I have never used a file upload in HTML before.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this... This will at least get you started. Still not complete, we can't do all the work for you ;-). Then you may want to get into PHP/.NET or other to do the actual upload.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<input type="file" id="myFile" multiple size="50" onchange="myFunction()">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction(){
    var x = document.getElementById("myFile");
    var txt = "";
    if ('files' in x) {
        if (x.files.length == 0) {
            txt = "Select one or more files.";
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < x.files.length; i++) {
                txt += "<br><strong>" + (i+1) + ". file</strong><br>";
                var file = x.files[i];
                if ('name' in file) {
                    txt += "name: " + file.name + "<br>";
                }
                if ('size' in file) {
                    txt += "size: " + file.size + " bytes <br>";
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    else {
        if (x.value == "") {
            txt += "Select one or more files.";
        } else {
            txt += "The files property is not supported by your browser!";
            txt  += "<br>The path of the selected file: " + x.value; // If the browser does not support the files property, it will return the path of the selected file instead. 
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>

<p><strong>Tip:</strong> Use the Control or the Shift key to select multiple files.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**Reference:** [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_fileupload_files.asp) (19-Dec-2017).

Comment: Thank you for the help! I will start my work from this.